# How can I use ngClass or toggle CSS in a function?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I'm trying to apply CSS based on a toggle. In this case, I'd like categories to be greyed out unless they are open. I have this working for the arrow, but this method won't work the same for the category.

[image]

Here is my current HTML:

```
<ion-item (tap)="togglefoods(list.category)" *ngIf="lists[i-1]?.category != list.category" class="categoryList">
    {{list.category}}
    <ion-icon item-right name="arrow-forward" *ngIf="list.category != currentCategory" style="color:#f0e6e3;"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon item-right name="arrow-down" *ngIf="list.category == currentCategory"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

Here is my TypeScript:

```
togglefoods(clickedCategory) {
  console.log(this.currentCategory,clickedCategory);
  if(this.currentCategory == clickedCategory){
    clickedCategory = null;
  }
  this.currentCategory = clickedCategory;
  console.log(clickedCategory)
}
```

Comment: Add the code for the list.

Comment: [ngClass]="{'gray':list.category != currentCategory,'green':list.category != currentCategory}", see, e.g. https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-classes-with-ngclass-and-ngstyle

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Obviously is [ngClass]="{'gray':list.category != currentCategory,'green':list.category == currentCategory}", (to quick copy && paste)